# Display random ACF gallery image and use image custom link

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, acfpro

We want to replace a slider with a clickable random image. So far I have half of this working using the below code that pulls one image from the ACF gallery and displays it.

What I can't seem to find is how to then use the image's custom link (as assigned when looaded into the WP media gallery), so that the image is also clickable (where the user loads the image and assigns the desired custom link).

Anyone have any idea how to get this to work?

Cheers!

```
<?php
$images = get_field('gallery', '', false);
$size = 'full';
$rand = array_rand($images ?? [null]);


if( $images ): ?>
<?php echo wp_get_attachment_image( $images[$rand], $size, "", $attr ); ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved! For those that want the solution, here is the code I bashed together to make an ACF Repeater powered random image with a custom link. Thanks @MindBorn for getting my brain working :)

```
    <?php
    $random_images = get_field('random_image_row');
    shuffle($random_images);
    $random_img_url = $random_images[0]['banner']['url'];
    $random_image_link = $random_images[0]['image_link'];
    ?>
    
    <div style="width:100%;">
<a href="<?php echo $random_image_link; ?>" > <img src="<?php echo $random_img_url; ?>" height="400" width="1920" /></a>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

By default in `Wordpress` attachments like images have four editable text fields available:

- alt-text
- title
- caption
- description

Probably not a good practice but for the record if you were to use one of these fields as the source for your image's custom link here's how to quickly access them:

```php
$images = get_field('gallery', '', false);
$size = 'full';
$rand = array_rand($images ?? [null]);
$image_id = $images[$rand];

$image_title = get_the_title($image_id);
$image_alt = get_post_meta($image_id, '_wp_attachment_image_alt', TRUE);
$image_caption = wp_get_attachment_caption($image_id);
$image_description = get_post_field('post_content', $image_id);
```

You haven't exactly clarified that but I suspect that you're actually using `ACF` fields group with image link custom field assigned to the attachment's form. I'd guess its type would be url then. If this is the case, you can simply access this field's value like this:

```php
$image_link = get_field('YOUR_CUSTOM_FIELD_NAME', $image_id);
```

Then it's just a matter of making your image clickable with the new url:

```php
if ($images) {
  $image_html = wp_get_attachment_image($image_id, $size);
  echo '<a href="'.$image_link.'">'.$image_html.'</a>';
}
```

Comment: Hey @MindBorn, many thanks for this. I actually started out using the ACF Gallery field, rather than a repeater, which is where that code applies. I tried amending it with your suggestion by adding: $image_link = get_the_post_thumbnail_url($thumbnail_url); And then with: if ($images) {
  $image_html = wp_get_attachment_image($image_id, $size);
  echo '<a href="'.$image_link.'">'.$image_html.'</a>’;
} but no dice and not that get_the_post_thumbnail_url is the correct call for the images Custom Link, but thought that may be a place to start. On the upside, the image is clickable!

Comment: @IAGT I think I need some more information

1. Are you using gallery or repeater field to store your images?
2. Where exactly is your image's link stored?
3. OR are you just trying to link the image to its full version? 

If (3) try this:
`$image_id = $images[$rand];`
`$image_link = wp_get_attachment_image_url($image_id);`

Comment: Ah, sorry :) The images for the banner are loaded into a ACF Gallery field - 'gallery'. The url I am trying to link each banner to is the 'Custom Link' for the image.

Comment: So I also tried `$image_link = wp_get_attachment_url($image_id);` which does click through to the image, so at one level it's working. The catch is I can't seem to find any reference to call the 'custom link' anywhere, which is odd, as it's a standard function for any WP image loaded into the/a gallery

Comment: OK! Problem to what I am trying to do solved... it can't be done as the 'Custom Link' is 'dynamically filed by ~wp-includes/js/media-views.js after you manually choose an image'. Looks like I'll have to go the ACF Repeater route...